# Mouse Over text for hyperlink jsp

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I'm unable to mouse over text for a hyperlink I created

```
input type="button" class="headermenubutton userLink"  id="admin" name="admin" value="Administration" title="Administration" onclick="onBtnAdmin()"                            
span title="Administration" class="linkSeparator" style="padding-left: 0px"
```

I added `title="Administration"` in span still doesn't seem to work

OnBtnAdmin is a button

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit ambiguous but as title suggests,you want mouse over text for a hyper link.This will work in your jsp.

```
<a href="url"><span title="I am hovering over the link text">link text</span></a>
```

The text which you will keep inside `span` tag will show mouse over text set by `title` property.